# Datetime Picker not Showing in UIWebView

Tags: safari, uiwebview, ios14, uiwebviewdelegate

My website is ***embedded*** in an iOS App using `UIWebView`, but devices running (since the update) `iOS 14` are not showing the `datetime picker`, contrary to `Safari App for iOS 14`.

Any idea of why this is not working anymore?
Thanks in advance.

iOS 14 app screeshots:

**Safari (expected in the UIWebview App!):**
[image]

**UIWebview App (Unexpected?):**
[image]

Comment: Not a solution but a suggestion - UIWebView is going away. Apple will stop accepting the apps that use UIWebView starting dec 2020, so it’s better to migrate to WKWebView.

Comment: I've not been able to look into this yet (still waiting for my iPhone to update) but our app uses WKWebview and apparently our test team are seeing the same thing.